# What software should I use to watch TV from an external TV card?

Tags: windows-7, tv

I bought a **Gigabyte U7300** DVB-T TV card, and tried it with three programs, but I still can't watch TV.

Do you have any suggestion which program would be good for this card? OS is Win 7.

Comment: Which programs did you try?

Comment: Windows Media Center, Vivo TV and Power Cinema. With Power Cinema I managed to find the channels, but after few seconds of watching it, it says "no signal".

Comment: I assume you have regular analog Cable signals coming in already? IE-if you hook up a directly to the cable outlet, you can watch channels?

Comment: @Luke: I used cable that is normally connected to TV (using DVB-T device), and the cable is connected to an exterior antenna, which works fine for TV set.

Comment: Which country are you based in ?

Comment: Bosnia and Herzegovina

Answer (score 4):

I use Imaging PVR software for my TV tuner card and find it very good if you're still looking. www.imagingpvr.co.uk

It does satellite TV and DVB-T which is also called DTT or Freeview.

I don't know where you are.  Their website says it works in Europe, Australia, South Africa, Russia, India, Middle East, Indonesia and Morocco.  The TV signal is different elsewhere apparently.

Comment: Is this freeware?

Answer (score 2):

Try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). One of it's [features](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) is to play DVB video(output stream format from analog TV cards):

> DVB (Satellite, Digital TV, Cable TV)

If it still doesn't work, consider looking at manufacturer's webpage to see it there is any specific codec, driver or software required to play TV streams from your external TV card.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this with VLC, step by step?

Comment: @MladenB: I can't tell you exactly the steps because I don't have a external TV card to create a VLC with TV guid for your. However, searching on google returned me few options: [youtube](www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSJ4QV3eg6k) / [a portuguese guid(must be translated to better understand)](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/1517-como-usar-vlc-media-player.htm) / [vlc forum](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=47474) / [tech blocg](http://www.kensfi.com/watch-live-tv-channels-streams-with-vlc-media-player/)

Comment: I found nothing useful here, there is no mention of DVB-T anywhere, only TV stream using internet, and I need this to work without internet.

Comment: Anyway VLC supports DVB-t inputs, as [features page](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) says. Take a look on internet for "watching DVB TV on VLC" and you certanlly find a way.